# Enable SQL Server Broker taking too long

Tags: sql-server-2005, service-broker

I have a Microsoft SQL server 2005 and I tried to enable Broker for my database with those T-SQL:

```
 SELECT name, is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases 
 -- checking its status 0 in my case
 ALTER DATABASE myDatabase SET ENABLE_BROKER
```

The `Alter Database` takes long time to process. It is now over half hour and it is still running. Not sure if it is waiting for something else or I have to clean up anything first, such as delete all the messages, contract, queue and services under service broker?

Comment: As a side note for others, if there are any open connections to the db, they would cause this delay.  Run `sp_who` to show if there are any.. (it might be you)

Answer (score 330, accepted):

http://rusanu.com/2006/01/30/how-long-should-i-expect-alter-databse-set-enable_broker-to-run/

```
alter database [<dbname>] set enable_broker with rollback immediate;
```

Comment: what is the effect of "with rollback immediate"?

Comment: @A.Dara You cannot alter a database as long as there are transactions pending. Rollback immediate will terminate all of these.

Comment: Transactions Smansactions. This is the way, especially if you're a financial institution.

Answer (score 20):

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE Database_Name
    SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
USE Database_Name;
GO
```

Answer (score 6):

Enabling SQL Server Service Broker requires a database lock.  Stop the SQL Server Agent and then execute the following:

```
USE master ;
GO

ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET ENABLE_BROKER ;
GO
```

Change [MyDatabase] with the name of your database in question and then start SQL Server Agent.

If you want to see all the databases that have Service Broker enabled or disabled, then query sys.databases, for instance:

```
SELECT
    name, database_id, is_broker_enabled
FROM sys.databases
```

Comment: It worked, I stopped SQL Server Agent and also had to end all db connections (take offline, bring online again)

Answer (score 3):

Actually I am  preferring to use `NEW_BROKER` ,it is working fine on all cases:

```
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Comment: you should explain why you prefer it and what it does differently....

Comment: It is working fine and without take a time in alll cases

Comment: This drops any in-flight messages.  Careful with this one (vs `ENABLE BROKER`)