# 'with rollback immediate' not working SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to enable service broker with rollback immediate, per this post: [Enable SQL Server Broker taking too long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094202/enable-sql-server-broker-taking-too-long-time)

here's the query:

```
alter database fooDB set enable_broker with rollback immediate;
```

However it's giving me the below syntax errors in SQL Server 2012:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'immediate'.
```

How can I do this in SQL Sever 2012?

Comment: Post the query giving you issues plz...appears your query is having this issue :  "If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon", so we would need your query to help you here.

Comment: I've added the query, it was copied from the other threrad

Comment: Does your real database have a space in the name?

Comment: no space is in the real dB name...

Comment: If your database has a space in the name it will cause a parsing error. alter database foo DB set enable_broker with rollback immediate; In this case you need to wrap your database name in square brackets. alter database [foo DB] set enable_broker with rollback immediate;

Comment: @SeanLange, there are no spaces in the DB name.

Comment: There is nothing wrong syntactically with that statement. There must be something else in your query window.

Comment: @Andrew yeah the OP posted that the same time as my comment.

Comment: Just FYI, this statement doesn't work if the server/database is participating in an "AlwaysOn" Availability Group cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrap it in it's own batch with preceding and terminating "GO" will help?

```
GO
alter database fooDB set enable_broker with rollback immediate;
GO
```

I just looked at the other post, are you trying to do this on a specific table or scripting is out to run dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

The `enable_broker` option requires an exclusive database lock. There should be no sessions having any locks on the altered DB, and it includes the session you run it in, as well:

```
use master;

alter database fooDB set enable_broker with rollback immediate;
```