# Bind DataGridView to a Table in Database

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource, mdf

I want to bind the DataGridView to a Table in my Database. I've found several topics about this, but I can't get it to work. Perhaps I'm missing something.

I'm building a "monitor" in which I want to see any Database changes of a specific table. So, after loading the data into a DataGridView, any change in that specific table should be propagate to the DataGridView.

Look what I've done:

```
    SqlDataAdapter daTab;
    DataTable dTable;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string s;
        s = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\tempDB\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn= new SqlConnection(s);
        conn.Open();

        daTab = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From tab", conn);
        dTable = new DataTable();
        daTab.Fill(dTable);
        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        bSource.DataSource = dTable;
        dgv1.DataSource = bSource;
    }
```

But it only updates the DataViewGrid when I run

```
daTab.Fill(dTable);
```

So I may have two options from here: 1) get it to work right (this is why I'm needing your help) or 2) put a timer and run `daTab.Fill(dTable);` at some time interval. I am particullary looking after option 1). So, I'd appreciate any help given.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're using SQL Server.  If so, have a look at the SqlDependency class.  You can create a delegate for this class's OnChange event and be notified of changes, which you can then propagate to your GridView.  Here is a good writeup on the topic with some examples:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks!! I created the `SqlDependency`, but now I'm getting SQL Server Service Broker problem. I tried to do a `ALTER DATABASE Temp SET ENABLE_BROKER;` but it gives error in the DATABASE word. It looks like SQL Server Compact does not support `ALTER DATABASE`.

Comment: I've never used Compact but take a look at this article.  It sounds like you need to have some kind of exclusive lock when setting enable_broker.  Wonder if that's your issue?  http://zarez.net/?p=755

Comment: Here's another user with enable_broker issues, but it's strange your're getting an error on the database word itself.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094202/enable-sql-server-broker-taking-too-long-time