# I cannot enable Service Broker on SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

When I try to send email using:

```
EXEC sp_send_dbmail
```

I get this error:

> Service Broker message delivery is not enabled in this database. Use the ALTER DATABASE statement to enable Service Broker message delivery.

So I am trying to execute:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabaseName] SET ENABLE_BROKER;
GO
```

But the above statement is running infinitely without error message or timeout.

When I run below statement:

```
select name, is_broker_enabled from sys.databases
```

I can see that service broker is still disabled.

Comment: That command requires a lock on the DB, so if you've got an active database, it's just going to wait until it can execute the ALTER.  An old, but similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094202/enable-sql-server-broker-taking-too-long

Comment: thanks Craig, adding: ' with rollback immediate;' did the job.